# Sending and retrieving data from one activity to another using ListView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview

i am making a quiz program to practice how listview works.

and i declare the strings.

```
    final String[] topics= {"History" , "Arts","Civics","Transport","Technology","Science", "Social",
            "Architecture", enter code here"Health","Geography","Computers","Business","Celebrities","Sports","Literature", "Music", };

now i use listview to see the list of items i have declared 

    Lst.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view,
                    int position, long id) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub

                Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
                bundle.putStringArray("Bundlekey", topics);



                String Topicname = topics[position];

                Intent intent = new Intent(QwizActivity.this,secondActivity.class);
                intent.putExtras(bundle);

                startActivity(intent);


            }
```

declaration of listview in xml `

```
<ListView
        android:id="@+id/ListVwe"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="#388E3C"
        android:elevation="2dp"
        android:textColor="#FFFFFF" >
    </ListView>`
```

i made a 2nd activity where i call the input from 1st activity and operate the input i get from bundle but i do not get any bundle value. it is null and i would like to compare each item for instance i select *history* i would like to have a different question for history and if i select *arts* i would like to have a question for arts . but i am not able to retrieve any value from the 1st activity i made a toast and the toast is empty. my be the methods i am using are incorrect . i am seeking for some guidance please help

the code where i declare a 2nd activity.

```
TextView Qsn ;
TextView TopicTitle ;   
Button  Ybtn    ;   
Button  Nbtn    ;



@Override protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
// TODO Auto-generated method stub
super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
setContentView(R.layout.history);

        Qsn =   (TextView) findViewById(R.id.Question);
        TopicTitle  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.Topictxt);
        Ybtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Yesbtn);
        Nbtn=(Button)findViewById(R.id.Nobtn);


        Intent intent = getIntent();

        Bundle bundle =intent.getExtras();
        String check=bundle.getString("Bundlekey") ;
        TopicTitle.setText(check);
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), check, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT)  .show();        
        }
```

xml for 2nd activity

```
android:id="@+id/Question"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="Question"

android:id="@+id/Topictxt"
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content"
     android:text="History"
```

my question is why is "**check**" empty and how do i compare "***check***" with the values like "*history*" sting "arts" sting etc. this is my 1st question so please bare me if i am not asking the question in a correct format. thankyou.

Comment: try to be more concise when asking question. +1 for effort

Answer (score 2):

You are senging an array with putStringArray from the OnItemClickListener and getting it as aString in the next Activity. Send Topicname instead.

```
String Topicname = topics[position];
bundle.putString("Bundlekey", Topicname);
```

Also you can make "Bundlekey" a  public static variable to access

Comment: hey thanks for help .. i think that was only the fault in the program. i changed it to putString instead of  putStringArray thanks and it worked

Answer (score 1):

While getting data in second Activity, you must get String Array from Bundle.

```
Bundle b=this.getIntent().getExtras();

String[] array=b.getStringArray(key);
```

and then get String values from this Array.

Answer (score 1):

to check what string you have received from the intent you may have to use a for loop for the array to compare each value in it.The below function will return the string which you have recieved

String compareValues(your array name,the value you have recieved)
{

```
String temp;
for(int i=0;i<array.length;i++)
{


if(value.equalsignorecase(array[i]))
temp = array[i];
break;

}
}
return temp;
}
```